# sprintf (or other function) for contitional formatting of integer / float

Tags: php

I need to display a number registered in database as a float

If the number ha no decimal part, is should be displayed as an int, and as a decimal in other cases.

Example :

```
8.00 should be displayed 8
8.45 should be displayed 8.45
```

The existing code uses a weird (but functionnal solution) using roud() :

```
if(round($number) == $number) {
 $number = round($number);
}
```

I wish to find some solution with sprintf by example, to have a more self-explicating code (the actual solution with round is not very understandable)

Does any of you faced this problem and knows a solution
(I've tried to play with sprintf() but I dit not managed how to have a variable number of decimals)

Comment: What's weird about that implementation?

Comment: What's wrong about that, nothing personal but it's more readable than Yoshi's solution

Comment: "the actual solution with round is not very understandable" what about using a comment?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$numbers = array(
    8.00, 8.45, 20.00, '8.00', '8.45', '20.00'
);

foreach ($numbers as $nr) {
    echo (string)(double)$nr, '<br />';
}
```

Comment: thanks for this trick. I choose this solution (more readable than the one with echo)

Comment: There is a reason why floats and integers exist as specific types with their appropriate functions. With the above code, the float `7E-10` would become `7E-1`, thus from `0.0000000007` it will become `0.7`.

Comment: @Shef You honestly think, from the given question, that kemar would run into this kind of problem?

Comment: @Yoshi: I honestly know for a fact that [MySQL uses scientific notations for floats](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math-numbers.html).

Comment: @Shef This is no answer to my question, and further more, why  don't you provide a better solution so we can discuss the pros and cons of that solution as well?

Comment: @Shef Yes? Which of the given solutions would display `$number = 7E-10;` as `0.0000000007`?  None, at least with my php version.

Comment: Yes, none, but the others won't alter it either. Anyways, the OP decides. You added your bits to it, so you did your job. :)

Comment: the solution with rtrim is not good : 
it fails if we want to convert 20.00 by example, we obtain '2'

Answer (score 0):

```
echo +'8.45';
```

will display 8.45 and

```
echo +'8.00';
```

will display 8 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure this is what you're looking for, but to shorten your rounding code into one statement, use this.

```
$number = (int)$number == $number ? (int)$number : $number;
```